# proof of an equality involving a second order homogeneous linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this following ODE:

$$\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^2} + a^{2}y = 0 \tag{eq.1}$$

The problem says that I should multiply it by $\frac{dy}{dx}$, proving that:

$$(\frac{dy}{dx})^{2} +a^{2}y^{2} = c^{2},$$ $c$ being a constant.

And it also asks me to find the general solution.

I am not familiarized with this kind of problem and I would appreciate someone to show me what am I supposed to do here.

What I did was finding the general solution of eq. 1, that is:

$$c1\cdot \cos(ax) + c2\cdot \sin(ax),$$
but I don't know if this is really part of what the problem is asking me to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying through eq.1 with $\frac{dy}{dx}$ gives
$$\left(\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}\right)\frac{dy}{dx}+a^{2}y\frac{dy}{dx}=0.$$
Hint on how to procced to prove what  you were asked:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))^{2}=2f(x)f'(x).$$

---

Your solution for the ODE looks correct and I have nothing to comment on that.